# Rust | Which is a better practice: using curly braces vs using parentheses around expression?

Tags: rust

In Rust you can write a foreach loop like this:

```
(0..arr.len()).for_each(|i| { // parens
  println!("Item: {}", arr[i]);
})
```

or like this:

```
{ 0..arr.len() }.for_each(|i| { // braces
  println!("Item: {}", arr[i]);
})
```

I know this isn't the smartest question, but which is correct? Which is the better practice?

Comment: Usually parethesis afik. Notice that by using curly braces you are creating a scope, which most of the times you will not need. But people here will correct me if Im wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first, using parentheses is more idiomatic.

You're just indicating operator precedence, so that `for_each` is called on the `Range` created by the `..` operator, rather than on `arr.len()`. This is one main function of parentheses.

The approach with curly braces creates a new [block expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/block-expr.html), which may contain multiple statements. The value of the last statement becomes the value of the block. It also gets the job done and probably compiles down to the same machine code, but is definitely a bit unusual in this case.

Comment: It is interesting that both options exist. The gleam language, another expression-oriented language, does away with parentheses entirely and even mathematical expressions use curly braces there

Comment: I don't see a reason why Rust couldn't do that as well. Possibly it was done to make Rust not look to alien to users coming from other C-like languages.